# If $m|(m-1)!$ then find $m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers $m$ such that $m|(m-1)!$.

Comment: Take cases. First suppose $m$ is prime. Next suppose $m = ab$, where $1<a<b<m$, There's one remaining case. I'll let you work that out.

Comment: $m=6$ is the first solution nor will $m$ ever be prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, when $m$ is a prime, $(m-1)!$ does not have $m$ as its factor.

Now, with the exceptions of number 2 and 4, all even numbers $n$ can be written as $\frac{n}{2}*2$. Clearly,by the definition of the factorial function, for an even number $n>4$, $(n-1)!$ contains both $\frac{n}{2}$ and $2$. **This means that $n$ will be a factor of $(n-1)!$ for all even numbers greater than 4.**

Now, for composite odd numbers $p$, it is apparent, by the definition of the factorial function, that $(p-1)!$ contains the factors making up $p$ [since (p-1)>factors of the composite number p besides itself].

Therefore, ***all even numbers besides 2 and 4***, and ***all composite odd numbers*** satisfy $m$ such that $\frac{(m-1)!}{m}\in Z^+$, which is what has been asked.

Comment: Just curious why did you mention $2$ as it is a prime, and why did you leave out $1$

Comment: $1$ divides $0!=1$ as $1=1 \cdot 1$, and is indeed neither composite nor prime, but is easy to forget and has to be special-cased anyways

Comment: Well, technically $m=p^2$, $p$ an odd prime, may require a bit of extra attention. In that case there is no way to write $m=ab$ in such a way that $a$ and $b$ are **distinct** and both appear as obvious factors in $(m-1)!$. But, when $p>2$, $p$ and $2p$ both appear as factors of $(m-1)!$ saving the day. It might have been simpler to structure your proof according to the cases: A)$m$ a prime (Wilson), B) $m$ the square of a prime ($p=2$ is exceptional, otherwise use the trick), C) other composites.